# Computed observable does not get notified of change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray, computed-observable

All of the code that is about to follow can be seen in action at this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLeE3/). I have left out the HTML data-binds and templates from this question, but they can be seen in the fiddle. I didn't think they were relevant to illustrating the problem.

---

#### Introduction

I'm attempting to link a computed observable to another object that I use as a HashMap.

The object with the computed observable is `HistoryEntry`:

```
function HistoryEntry(userId, users) {
    this.UserId = ko.observable(userId);

    this.User = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!users[this.UserId()]) return '(' + this.UserId() + ')';
        return '(' + this.UserId() + ') ' + users[this.UserId()].Name();
    }, this);
}
```

The `HistoryEntry` contains a `UserId` which serves as the lookup value in my JavaScript object serving as a HashMap. `users` is a reference back to this HashMap contained in the ViewModel.

The HashMap contains `User` objects keyed by their `UserId`. The `User` object is as follows:

```
function User(id, name) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
}
```

The idea is that the computed observable, `HistoryEntry.User()` will lookup the name from the corresponding `User` object in this HashMap.

The HashMap is stored on the parent ViewModel, along with the observable array of `HistoryEntry` objects:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.users = ko.observable({
        '16': new User(16, 'Jack'),
        '17': new User(17, 'Jill')
    });

    this.history = ko.observableArray([
        new HistoryEntry(16, this.users()),
        new HistoryEntry(17, this.users()),
        new HistoryEntry(18, this.users())
    ]);
}

var view = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(view);
```

#### The Problem

As you can see above, I've created only two users, yet I have three history entries, each pointing to a different user. One of these entries refers to a User(18) that doesn't yet exist in the HashMap.

For my example, I change User(16)'s name from 'Jack' to 'John' and add User(18):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    view.users()[16].Name('John');
    view.users()[18] = new User(18, 'Bill');
    view.users.valueHasMutated();
    view.history.valueHasMutated();
}, 1000);
```

This correctly updates the `HistoryEntry` that has a computed observable pointing to User(16).

Likewise, I expected that when I add User(18), the `HistoryEntry` with a computed observable to User(18) would update with the name of User(18).

Unfortunately, it does not.

#### Questions

1. I'd like a deeper understanding of why the `HistoryEntry` pointing to User(18) isn't getting notified of the change, now that User(18) does exist.
2. Moreover, I need to find a solution that will update the `HistoryEntry` pointing to User(18) when User(18) is added to the users HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HistoryEntry wont get updated because you're not unwrapping `users` wihin the computed.

Try changing

```
new HistoryEntry(18, this.users())
```

To

```
new HistoryEntry(16, this.users)
```

Then change `HistoryEntry` to:

```
function HistoryEntry(userId, users) {
    this.UserId = ko.observable(userId);

    this.User = ko.computed(function () {
        var usersArr = ko.unwrap(users);
        if (!usersArr[this.UserId()]) return '(' + this.UserId() + ')';
        return '(' + this.UserId() + ') ' + usersArr[this.UserId()].Name();
    }, this);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/W6nRe/

Computeds keep track of all the observables that are used within the computed, since you were using the underlying users object, it didn't have a reference to users. So computeds only get updated if one of the observables it uses is changed.

Comment: In your fiddle, I do not see the Name of User(18) appearing in the history table after User(18) is added. The last entry of the history table should read `18 (18) Bill` but it reads `18 (18)`

Comment: Yeah, I edited the answer already. I placed the unwrap code in the wrong place.

Comment: That's weird. When I clicked the "An edit has been made", it didn't actually refresh your answer! I see it working now. If you would, could you explain a little bit about why I need to `unwrap` inside of the computed observable? Thanks!